# Equivalence and partition question ,need help with reflexive property

Tags: equivalence-relations, advice

Let R be the set of the real numbers. Prove $\{G_r\}_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Let $G_r= \{(x,y) :x^2+y^2=r\}$.  For each $r∈R$

I have to do 3 things:

1. Prove it is a partition.
2. Find it’s equivalence class.

   3.describe geometrically.

I done 3.

2. Done by Mr Diaz
   To prove 1, I have to prove that it’s subsets are disjoint and form G, correct ?

Given G_r
Is it enough to do this:

[Prove that given a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of a set $A$ nonempty, there exists a unique equivalence relation on $A$ from which it is derived](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659492/prove-that-given-a-partition-mathcalp-of-a-set-a-nonempty-there-exists-a)

My dilemma the problem is set up in order to prove P without 
referring to 2?

So, if it is reflexive, then $x \sim x$ implies that $x-x=0$ so that $x^2 + y^2=x^2+y^2$ implies that $x^2-x^2=y^2-y^2=r-r=0

I have no problem with the other properties.

“~” equivalent to

I have another attempt which makes no sense, so I won’t 
write. This is my best attempt...

When Pinter stated for each $r∈R$ I thought I could 
assume it could mean for all of them

Comment: First of all, it is not possible that $x^2 + y^2 = r$ for all $r \geq 0$ because that would imply that $0 = 1,$ for instance. Further, I am not certain what you mean by $\sim.$ Can you clarify that $a \sim b$ if and only if what happens?

Comment: How is $G$ defined? Is it that $(a,b) G (c,d)$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$?

Comment: Nope. I gave all the info the question has

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the exercise of the book, you need to find the equivalence relation that corresponds to the partition.

Define this relation: Let $(x_{1}, y_{1}), (x_{2}, y_{2})\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $(x_{1}, y_{1})\sim(x_{2}, y_{2})$ iff $x_{1}^{2} + y_{1}^{2} = x_{2}^{2}+ y_{2}^{2}$

It is reflexive on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, since $x_{1}^{2} + y_{1}^{2} = x_{1}^{2}+ y_{1}^{2} \leftrightarrow (x_{1}, y_{1})\sim(x_{1}, y_{1}), \forall (x_{1}, y_{1})\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: Sorry, but what you did was not the exact problem of the book.

Comment: Here is the problem...https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=q1KVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=Pinter,+G+is+an+equivalence+relation+G+R%3D+%7B(x,y)+:x%5E2%2By%5E2%3Dr%7D&source=bl&ots=clLuMPSuKa&sig=ACfU3U0iYeLUQRkBR-P2sDBLDojmpKR7Uw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb0NST_fLpAhUrIbkGHaZoBC4Q6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=Pinter%2C%20G%20is%20an%20equivalence%20relation%20G%20R%3D%20%7B(x%2Cy)%20%3Ax%5E2%2By%5E2%3Dr%7D&f=false

Comment: I don’t understand why?